# Как правильно подключить библиотеку Codemirror к Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular4, angular5, codemirror

Документация здесь http://codemirror.net
И для ангуляр: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-codemirror

Установил:
1) npm install ng2-codemirror
2) npm install codemirror
3) В app.module.ts подключил

```
import { CodemirrorModule } from 'ng2-codemirror';
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports:      [
    CodemirrorModule
  ],
  // ...
})
```

4) В .angular-cli.json подключил

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"
  ],
```

5) Вместо textarea написал

```
<codemirror
  *ngIf="chaptersService.currentChapter" 
  [(ngModel)]="chaptersService.currentChapter.novel"
  [config]="{lineNumbers: true}"
  autofocus
  (keyup)="markAsEdited()"
  #textareaNovel>
</codemirror>
```

Классы применяются от Codemirror, но вводить текст не получаеться,
что не так делаю ?

Comment: А в консоле нет ошибок?

Comment: Нет ошибок в консоли.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать все дополнительные атрибуты, такие как `*ngIf`, `[(ngModel)]` и прочее. Возможно, есть какие-то конфликты.

Comment: Убрал не помогает.

Comment: Поясните что означает "вводить текст не получаеться". Что делаете, что происходит.